# Daloradius attribute issue: sql: Failed to create the pair: Unknown name

Tags: freeradius, centos8

I followed steps in the link below to build a freeradius with daloradius on my CentOS 8 VM:
https://computingforgeeks.com/install-freeradius-and-daloradius-on-centos-rhel-8/

On daloradius, I created a new vendor and a new attrinute as below:
[New Vendor and Atribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x57i.png)
Then I also created a user as below:
[User1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meC2L.png)
[User2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbH9i.png)

However, if I tried to access the radius server by the command below:
"radtest tester1 1111  192.168.123.87 0 secret1234",
I would get "Access-Reject".

From the radius.log, I could see error below:

```
"Wed Mar  2 03:27:39 2022 : Auth: (2) Login incorrect (sql: Failed to create the pair: Unknown name "Caswell-CW_group"): [tester1] (from client my_lan port 0)"
```

I have tried to check from my radius server via MariaDB and I could see below:
[DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QNkF.png)

So, I can not understand why I would get access-rejected and why sql would said Unknown name.

If I delete the check attribute in the user account "tester1", I could get access "Access-accept".

Do I miss anything in my settings on radius server?

Answer (score 1):

I have founded the answer for my issue.
If I want to add a new vendor and attributes, I will need to add a new file under the path: /usr/share/freeradius/.For example, if I want to add a new vendor like "fortesting" and an new attribute "testing attribute".
I will need to add a new file called "dictionary.fortesting". And then I will need to modify the file "/usr/share/freeradius/dictionary" to include the file "dictionary.fortesting". After doing steps above, restating freeradius service. And then log in the WEB UI of daloradius, creating the same vendor and attributes.At last, I will be able to use the new vendor and attributes in my freeradius users.I will get " Access-Accept" while using the command "radtest".

Comment: Hey, I want my attribute to have a statis value how can I define the dictionary for that? `# Custom RADIUS dictionary entry
ATTRIBUTE Has-Log-Access 1 string
VALUE Has-Log-Access "yes"` I've set this but it gives me this error `Errors reading dictionary: dict_init: /usr/share/freeradius/dictionary.permission[3]: invalid VALUE line
`